# How to submit data then post on another page mongoDB/Node.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am needing to have 1 page of a website submit data to MongoDB then pull that same data and display it on a different page. I am using node.js, express, Mongoose, and MongoDB.

Currently, I have it so It gets submitted properly to the database, and I can see it with the correct layout, But I cannot seem to get it posted on the page.

How exactly do I go about doing this?
Can someone give a example of code of this?

I am really new to this stuff and still learning.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> In the route of the page you want to load, use the Mongoose `.find()` 
>   method. 
>   You can use `{}` in the `find()` method to return all the data, or access 
>   individual data based on the object key `find({id:'value'})`. Then when you 
>   render the page, just pass in an object to the render, where the key is
>   what you access in the url page, in my example you would use
>   (`mongs`) to access the values within the url page (.ejs, etc). So in
>   your route definition file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    MongModel.find({}, (err, foundMongModel) => {
        err ? console.log(err) : res.render('url/route', { mongs: foundMongModel });
    });
});
```

> Then if you're using .ejs file, you would need to use `<%= %>` to access 
>   individual data, and `<% %>` to use a loop or something. 
>   and use the `mongs` value. So if you imported all the data from the 
>   database, you could loop through it using

```
<% mongs.forEach(mong =>{ %>
        <div>mong.key<div>
<% }) %>
```

> You can access the keys for each database object like above using 
>   `mong.key`